# UART driver for QEMU receiving `delete` byte instead of `backspace`

Tags: c, serial-port, qemu, uart

I press the backspace button on my keyboard, I get the `delete` byte, which is 127 instead of 8, which is the representative of `backspace` using the following simple get/put UART functions.

```c
#define mmio_write_byte(base, offset, value) \
    *((uint8_t *) (base + offset)) = (uint8_t) value

#define mmio_read_byte(base, offset) *((uint8_t *) (base + offset))

void uart0_put(char c) {
    while ((mmio_read_byte(UART0_BASE, UART_LSR) & (1 << 5)) == 0);
    mmio_write_byte(UART0_BASE, UART_THR, c);
}

char uart0_get() {
    while ((mmio_read_byte(UART0_BASE, UART_LSR) & (1 << 0)) == 0);
    return mmio_read_byte(UART0_BASE, UART_RHR);
}
```

In my driver code, I have the following:

```c
    while (1) {
        char c = read_char();
        if (c == 127) {
            puts("HERE: delete\n");
        } else if (c == 8) {
            puts("HERE: backspace\n");
        } else if (c == 10 || c == 13) {
            putchar('\n');
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
```

When I run QEMU and press the backspace button repeatedly on my keyboard, I receive the following:

```
$ qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -smp 1 -bios none -m 128 -serial mon:stdio -nographic -device virtio-keyboard-device -kernel kernel/kernel.elf
HERE: delete
HERE: delete
HERE: delete
```

Also, when I press the `delete` button, I don't get anything printed (so it doesn't map to 8 nor 127)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the correct behaviour. If you press the backspace key on the keyboard it's function is **delete** the character behind the cursor, not to move the cursor back without deleting.

The `delete` button does not translate to any ASCII char. It is internal to the terminal but not sent.